# Will installing chrome canary automatically install stable version of chrome too?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

Using windows 8 and srware iron I didn't need chrome for a while.
But from time to time chrome-specific feature like google image search is needed for research so I decided to go out wild and install chrome canary this time--I liked it better for speed when I installed it last time on other pc.
However it didn't initially but after some time it seems chrome stable version got in the way and installed itself automatically.
Is it supposed to happen? or did I probably do something stupid and installed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Have you tried to install it again yet?** The Chrome Canary installer does not automatically install the stable version of Chrome. It seems that you may have accidentally chosen the wrong installer from Google's webpage. I think this is the case because it is possible to have both regular Chrome and Canary side-by-side on a computer (they don't overwrite each other), so there's no chance that your installation got tampered with or overwritten after installation.

Comment: Once I noticed I just removed stable and left canary untouched. Do you advise to delete and re-install canary? I probably assumed wrong that google updater that comes with canary will eventually install chrome stable too and that caused my situation.

Comment: Try running Canary for awhile. If you want to force the update and see if the issue arises again, go to chrome://help and wait for it to download the latest update, if there is one. The problem seems to be fairly isolated, and I don't think it will be reproducible.